# How can I derive the general formula for the standard deviation of an arithmetic series?

Tags: summation, standard-deviation, arithmetic-progressions

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Standard_deviation) wikipedia article, the standard deviation of an arithmetic series has the following [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwN78.png), in terms of the common difference $d$ and number of terms $n$. The article does not cite the source, nor could I find the derivation elsewhere on the internet. I've tried to derive it myself, however, the algebra got a bit crazy and I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to derive this.

So far, I've tried plugging in the nth terms of an arithmetic series into the standard deviation formula:

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2}$

Focussing on the sum ($x_i$ is the $i$th term of an arithmetic series):

$\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2 = \sum (x_i^2) + \sum(\mu^2) - \sum (2\mu x_i) $

The second term is simply $ n\mu^2 $.

The final term is simply $ \sum (2\mu x_i) = 2\mu \sum(x_i) = \mu n(2a_1 + (n-1)d)$.

For the first term:

$\sum (x_i^2)= \sum (a_1 + (i-1)d)^2 = $

$ \sum(a_1^2) + \sum d^2(i-1)^2 + \sum 2a_1(i-1)d = $

$ na_1^2 + d^2( \sum i^2 + \sum 1^2 - \sum 2i) + 2a_1d \sum (i-1) =$

$ na_1^2 + d^2( \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + n - n(n+1)) + 2a_1d ( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n) $

At this point I have put everything in terms of $ a_1 $, $d$ and $n$, ( $\mu$ can easily be written in terms of $n$ and $d$). However, I am unable to simplify this crazy expression and have no idea how to simplify it to the extent shown in the wikipedia article, and don't even know if I am on the right track and didn't make some stupid mistake. Can someone else guide me?

Answer (score 2):

Writing the progression "symmetrically" clarifies things.

I'll work the case where $n=2k+1$ is odd, the other is similar.

We can write the terms as $$\{\mu-kd, \cdots,\mu-d, \mu, \mu+d, \cdots, \mu+kd\}$$

We see that $$\sigma^2=\frac 1n\times 2\sum_{i=1}^k(id)^2=\frac {2d^2}{n}\frac {k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}= {d^2}\frac {k(k+1)}{3}$$

And the desired result follows instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is to use linear coding, i.e. $$Var (aX+b)=a^2Var (X)$$

First find the standard deviation of the first $n$ consecutive integers:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r=\frac{n(n+1}{2}\implies \bar{X}=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^2=\frac n6(n+1)(2n+1)$$

Now $$Var(X)=\frac{\sum X^2}{n}-\bar{X}^2$$

$$=\frac16(n+1)(2n+1)-\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{12}$$

Now apply the coding and square root to get the standard deviation and get the result $$|d|\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{12}}$$